# Android import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI; Failed

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hello i am trying to add `Firebase Auth UI` in my application and added all required dependency but still android studio giving me this error `Cannot resolve symbol 'AuthUI` i tried on a different system and its works without any problem but on my workstation its not. My Android Studio version is 3.13

**My build.gradle**

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Comment: You may try the 'Invalidate Caches/Restart'  in the File menu .

Comment: Have you solved the issue?